# Inaccurate Facebook Insights

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get engagement information from facebook. I am having some weird scenarios where for a given post `post_engaged_users` is greater than `post_impressions_unique` (for example 192/146). Based of of the descriptions:

`post_impressions_unique: Lifetime:` The number of people who saw your Page post. (Unique Users)

`post_engaged_users: Lifetime:` The number of people who clicked anywhere in your posts. (Unique Users)

Based off these descriptions I feel like `post_engaged_users` should be a subset of `post_impressions_unique` and always be smaller. Am I misinterpreting the descriptions or is facebook insight metrics just not that reliable?